# Click event improperly changing all React components of the same type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an `onClick` event set up for a component that is rendered multiple times.  When this onClick is triggered, text inside a button determined by a JS variable is changed.  However, when I click a button for one component the text changes for all other components of this same type.  Here is the code:

**FormEntity.js:**

```
import React from 'react';

let hasFile = false;
let uploadBtnText = 'Simulate file upload';
const FormEntity = (props) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
      if(hasFile) {
        props.formInstanceRemoved(props.instanceId);
        hasFile = false;
        uploadBtnText = 'Simulate file upload';
      } else {
        props.formInstanceUploaded(props.instanceId, props.blueprintId);
        hasFile = true;
        uploadBtnText = 'Remove file';
      }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}> {uploadBtnText} </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormEntity;
```

Here is a picture that should help further show the problem.

[image]

Clicking a button should only effect the text and whatever else is within that button, not all the other components too.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want each button to have its own state, so you should define the buttons as stateful ones and use `setState`. Your current implementation changes module-level variables, which are shared by all instances of the button.

```
const FormEntity extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hasFile: false,
      uploadBtnText: 'Simulate file upload',
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    if (this.state.hasFile) {
      this.props.formInstanceRemoved(props.instanceId);
      this.setState({
        hasFile: false,
        uploadBtnText: 'Simulate file upload',
      });
    } else {
      this.props.formInstanceUploaded(props.instanceId, props.blueprintId);
      this.setState({
        hasFile: true,
        uploadBtnText: 'Remove file',
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}> {uploadBtnText} </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably include your `FormEntity` per `import / require`. Therefore all instances of the imported component `FormEntity` share the same `uploadBtnText` variable. 
Whenever it is changed in an instance of a particular `FormEntity`, because it is shared, all other instances of `FormEntity` get also updated.

I would suggest to refactor your stateless functional `FormEntity` to a standard component and write `uploadBtnText` in its state.